# How do I render a multiple-model CREATE form on the fly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

It's a multi-model view, and I'm achieving this through an `IList<Book>`.  Each Book has a Title and an Author

So for example if I wanted to make 3 Books:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[0].Title) %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[0].Author) %>

<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[1].Title) %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[1].Author) %>

<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[2].Title) %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[2].Author) %>
```

and so forth.

However, I want to be able to generate such a form for any number of Books.  I've done this before in Ruby on Rails through JavaScript and rendering partials, but I don't think I can render a partial in this case because the form changes (the index of the book has to increment for it to work)

EDIT: I'm looking for a way to do this in the **Create** view in particular.  So in this case I don't have a list of books, but I'm building it.

A user should be able to click on a link that says "Add another item" and a form for another book should be appended to the bottom.

Any ideas?  Some sample code would be extremely helpful (I'm very new to ASP.NET)!

Answer (score 1):

[Editor templates](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/04/26/mvc-2-templates/) are a great way to achieve this:

Model:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Fetch the books from your repository:
    var books = new[]
    {
        new Book { Title = "title 1", Author = "author 1" },
        new Book { Title = "title 2", Author = "author 2" },
    };
    return View(books);
}
```

View `~/Views/Home/Index.aspx` (strongly typed to `IEnumerable<Book>`):

```
<%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
```

Editor template `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Book.ascx` (strongly typed to `Book`):

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Title) %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Author) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
<%
foreach (var book in Model)
{
    %>
    <p>Title: <%= Html.TextBoxFor(book.Title) %></p>
    <p>Author: <%= Html.TextBoxFor(book.Author) %></p>
    <%
}
%>
```

You can use most C# code within a view, inside `<% %>` blocks.

Comment: What would you recommend for adding the actual form elements to the view?

I was thinking that a user could just click "Add Another Book" and an additional form for a book would be appended to the form collection, but how should I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Send a list to the view and loop through using foreach.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx

## EDIT:

I answered a similar question yesterday.  This is Web Forms but it should work in MVC as well

[Programmatically add controls to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199629/programmatically-add-controls-to-form/3199875#3199875)

Comment: This would work for something like an Edit view, where I know what my list is.  But how would I have something where I could click an "Add another item" in the Create view and have it append another form for a Book?

Comment: I've edited my answer with another SO answer I made yesterday (sorry it's in VB).  The idea is to create a collection `List(Of T)` and add a new set of controls to that list every time a button is clicked (when a form is submitted)